# Estimate the integral $\int_1^2(x+.1(\sin(x))^3)~dx$ from above and below.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

this is a weird case that I'm not sure how to do.

$$\int_1^2(x+.1(\sin(x))^3)~dx$$ from above and below.

Comment: i tried to fix latex, but there seems to missing few things ... could you recheck your question again?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\sin^3x=\sin x-\sin\cos^2x\implies \int\sin^3x\;dx=-\cos x+\frac13\cos^3x+C$$

Comment: I'll try and use that but I'm not completely sure yet how that'll help. thanks

Comment: Well, your integral is $$\int x\,dx+\frac1{10}\int\sin^3x\,dx$$so I'd say that helps quite a bit...

Comment: that it does!!!!